# unexpected unindent (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

There is a "unexpected unindent" in this code for Discord.py the code is:

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("The Member Was Kicked.")
```

the full code:

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions, is_owner
import json

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
status=discord.Status.idle

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("The Member Was Banned.")

  @client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("The Member Was Kicked.")

  
@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


my_secret = os.environ['Token']

client.run(my_secret)
```

Comment: Your `@client.command()` is clearly indented incorrectly. It should be at the same indentation level as the `async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):` on the line below.

Comment: The indentation is different between your first and second snippets, you need to make an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

### Bugs

`Line 16`

```py
  @client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("The Member Was Kicked.")
```

It is clearly visible that the first line is not indented correctly.

`line 24`

```
@client.event
async def on_ready():
 print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
```

Here, the third line is not indented correctly.

Fixing the indentation, your code should look like the following

```py
import os
import discord
import json

from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions, is_owner


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
status = discord.Status.idle

@client.command()
async def ban(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("The Member Was Banned.")


@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("The Member Was Kicked.")

  
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('we have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


my_secret = os.environ['Token']
client.run(my_secret)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a discord.py issue.
Your indentation in flawed

Line 16

```
  @client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("The Member Was Kicked.")
```

instead it should be

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send("The Member Was Kicked.")
```

If this doesnt fix your problem , check if you used tabs instead of spaces or vice versa.